# R Shiny: checkbox logic (if/else) - Why only the output of the last condition can be shown alone?

Tags: r, shiny, logic, shiny-server, shinyapps

This is a simplified version of my project. It has two checkboxes: 'simple' and 'logistic'. 
I hope to have the regression line shown when the corresponding checkbox is checked.

Here is what happens when I run my code:

- When both boxes are checked: two regression lines show
- When only the 'simple' box is checked: the simple regression line shows
- BUT when only the 'logistic' box is checked: NOTHING SHOWS

I don't understand why this is happening or how to solve the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$linePlot <- renderPlotly({

        x<- seq(-10,10,0.1)
        y1<- x*input$b1+input$a1
        y2<- 1/(1+exp(-input$a2-input$b2*x))

        #plot
        p<-plot_ly()%>%
            layout(xaxis = list(range=c(-10,10)), yaxis = list(range=c(-32,32)))

        if (input$logistic){
            p<-p%>%
                add_trace(x=x,y=y2,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "y2=1/(exp(-a2-b2*x))", line = list(color = 'rgb(22, 96, 167)'))
        }

        if (input$simple){
            p<-p%>%
                add_trace(x=x,y=y1,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "y1=a1+b1*x",line = list(color = 'rgb(255, 129, 10)'))
        }
    })
}
```

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Regression Line Simulator"),

    # Sidebar with four slider inputs for a1, a2, b1, b2
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # checkboxGroupInput("regression", label = "Type of regression", 
            #                    choices = list("Simple Linear" = 1, "Logistic" = 2),
            #                    selected = c(1,2)),
            # 
            checkboxInput("simple","Simple Regression", value = TRUE),
            checkboxInput("logistic", "Logistic Regression", value = TRUE),
            helpText("Select values on the sliders"),

            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.simple==true",
                sliderInput("a1","Select value for a1",min = -0.8,max = 0.8,value = 0,step = 0.1),
                sliderInput("b1","Select value for b1",min = -3,max = 3,value = 0,step = 0.1),
                sliderInput("sd1","Select the standard deviation for y1_data",min = 0.1,max = 2.0,value = 0.1,step = 0.1),
            ),

            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.logistic==true",
                sliderInput("a2", "Select value for a2",min = -0.8,max = 0.8,value = 0,step = 0.1),
                sliderInput("b2","Select value for b2",min = -3,max = 3,value = 0,step = 0.1),
                sliderInput("sd2","Select the standard deviation for y2_data",min = 0.1, max = 2.0,value = 0.1,step = 0.1)

            ),

            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.simple==true||input.logistic==true",
                sliderInput("size", "Select the sample size",min = 5,max = 20,value = 5,step = 1),
                actionButton("simulate", "Simulate!"),
                actionButton("clear", "Clear"))

        ),
            # Show a plot of the generated distribution
            mainPanel(
                plotlyOutput("linePlot")
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to return `p` at the end of your `renderPlotly`:

```
output$linePlot <- renderPlotly({

    x<- seq(-10,10,0.1)
    y1<- x*input$b1+input$a1
    y2<- 1/(1+exp(-input$a2-input$b2*x))

    #plot
    p<-plot_ly()%>%
        layout(xaxis = list(range=c(-10,10)), yaxis = list(range=c(-32,32)))

    if (input$logistic){
        p<-p%>%
            add_trace(x=x,y=y2,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "y2=1/(exp(-a2-b2*x))", line = list(color = 'rgb(22, 96, 167)'))
    }

    if (input$simple){
        p<-p%>%
            add_trace(x=x,y=y1,type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', name = "y1=a1+b1*x",line = list(color = 'rgb(255, 129, 10)'))
    }

    p
})
```

Comment: Right, thank you!!!  I am new to R, so I don't understand why I have to return p. Could you kindly explain the reason?

Comment: The last element inside a function is the one the function will return

Comment: @h-karyn This is like a function. It has to return something. In fact it is harder to understand why your code partly worked.